# How to iteratively add rows to an inital empty pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have to iteratively add rows to a pandas DataFrame and find this quite hard to achieve. Also performance-wise I'm not sure if this is the best approach.

So from time to time, I get data from a server and this new dataset from the server will be a new row in my pandas DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame([], columns=['Timestamp', 'Value'])

# as this df will grow over time, is this a costly copy (df = df.append) or does pandas does some optimization there, or is there a better way to achieve this?
# ignore_index, as I want the index to automatically increment
df = df.append({'Timestamp': datetime.datetime.now()}, ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

After one day the DataFrame will be deleted, but during this time, probably 100k times a new row with data will be added.

The goal is still to achieve this in a very efficient way, runtime-wise (memory doesn't matter too much as enough RAM is present).

Comment: Do you need the data to stay in the DataFrame format all day long? An `append` on a list is way cheaper since there is no copying. You can keep the data as list-of-dicts, then assemble the dataframe once at the end of the day, or whenever you need to run your analysis.

Comment: My problem or the actual reason why I would like to use pandas DataFrame over pure lists is, that after a new row is added, I need to calculate a lot of measures every single time and found this easier to be done with a simple DataFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this to compare the speed of 'append' compared to 'loc' :

```py
import timeit

code = """
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(0, 6), 'B' : range(0,6)})
df= df.append({'A' : 3, 'B' : 4}, ignore_index = True)
"""

code2 = """
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(0, 6), 'B' : range(0,6)})
df.loc[df.index.max()+1, :] = [3, 4]
"""

elapsed_time1 = timeit.timeit(code, number = 1000)/1000
elapsed_time2 = timeit.timeit(code2, number = 1000)/1000
print('With "append" :',elapsed_time1)
print('With "loc" :' , elapsed_time2)
```

On my machine, I obtained these results :

```
With "append" : 0.001502693824000744
With "loc" : 0.0010836279180002747
```

Using "loc" seems to be faster.